# RestKit not posting to server

Tags: http, post, mapping, restkit

I'm new to objective and rest kit.My code runs without errors but the server doesn't show any post request being made.the url and method names are correct, is there something else i'm missing ?

below is the code i'm using

```
-(void)construct
  {
    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);
    URL = @"http://xx.xx.xx.xx:80/CW_war/getMyOffersCount";
  }


- (void)run{

    //mapping request object
    RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CountResultVO class]];
    [mapping mapKeyPath:@"offercount" toAttribute:@"offercount"];
    [mapping mapKeyPath:@"insertCount" toAttribute:@"insertCount"];
    [mapping mapKeyPath:@"favouriteOfferCount" toAttribute:@"favouriteOfferCount"];
    [mapping mapKeyPath:@"favouriteInsertCount" toAttribute:@"favouriteInsertCount"];

     //set mapping
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider addObjectMapping:mapping];forKeyPath:@"articles"];


    //serializing post object
    RKObjectMapping* outSerializationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]];
    [outSerializationMapping mapAttributes:@"userId", @"userId", @"mode", @"mode", nil]; 
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:outSerializationMapping forClass:[BasicUserArgVo class]]; 

    //setting post params
    RKObjectManager* manager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:URL];
    manager.acceptMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON; 
    manager.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON; 

    //setting post object router
    [manager.router routeClass:[BasicUserArgVo class] 
                toResourcePath:@"/getMyOffersCount" 
                     forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];
    //init post object
    BasicUserArgVo *bvo = [[BasicUserArgVo alloc]initWithUserId:5 andMode:nil];

    //post object BasicUserArgVo and map to CountResultVO
    [manager postObject:bvo mapResponseWith:mapping delegate:self];

}

- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObject:(NSArray*)objects {
    NSLog(@"hello");
    CountResultVO* countResultVO = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"RESULT : %ld %ld",[countResultVO offercount],[countResultVO insertCount]);

}

- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]]);
}
```

================================================================

edit:

the objects-

```
@interface CountResultVO : NSObject
{
    long offercount;
    long insertCount;
    long favouriteOfferCount;
    long favouriteInsertCount;
}
@property(nonatomic,readwrite) long offercount;
@property(nonatomic,readwrite) long insertCount;
@property(nonatomic,readwrite) long favouriteOfferCount;
@property(nonatomic,readwrite) long favouriteInsertCount;

@end
```

and

```
@interface BasicUserArgVo : NSObject
{
    long userId;
    NSString *mode;
}

@property(nonatomic,readwrite) long userId;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString * mode;
-(id)initWithUserId:(long)uid andMode:(NSString *)m;
-(id)initWithUserId:(long)uid;
@end
```

and i'm calling the (void)run method in my apps viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    RestKitUtil *restKitUtil = [[RestKitUtil alloc]init];
    [restKitUtil run];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: And, you can use NSString instead of long type ?? I do not know if you can map long !? And after if you want your long value with a string :[countResultVO.offercount longLongValue] for exemple. If he can not handle long type it will not recognize the serialization object. Do you have RestKit traces/logs ? Are you sur that your construct method is called ?

Comment: there's not much log, just 

[806:fb03] I restkit:RKLog.m:30 RestKit initialized...

i call construct and then run.

Comment: I see you blocked out your URL, that's fine, but are you really going to port 80? Did you mean 8080 instead?

Comment: it's set to port 80, i tried
`code`
RKClient *client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURL:@"http://10.6.10.121:80/CW_war/"];

NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"5" ,@"userId",@"0",@"mode",nil];

[ [RKClient sharedClient] post:@"/getMyOffersCount" params:params delegate:self];
`code`

this at least makes the server throw an "unsupported media type, cannot consume content" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I change few elements, but if this one don't solve your problem i need more code and traces. It is possible to see your VO code ?

Do you realy have "userId" and "mode" attributes in BasicUserArgVo object ? If not this can be your problem.

```
-(void)construct
{
    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);
    URL = @"http://xx.xx.xx.xx:80/CW_war/getMyOffersCount";

    //setting post params
    RKObjectManager* manager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:URL];
    [RKObjectManager sharedManager].acceptMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON; 
    [RKObjectManager sharedManager].serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;

    //mapping request object
    RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CountResultVO class]];
    [mapping mapKeyPath:@"offercount" toAttribute:@"offercount"];
    [mapping mapKeyPath:@"insertCount" toAttribute:@"insertCount"];
    [mapping mapKeyPath:@"favouriteOfferCount" toAttribute:@"favouriteOfferCount"];
    [mapping mapKeyPath:@"favouriteInsertCount" toAttribute:@"favouriteInsertCount"];

    //set mapping [I change called method, there seems to be a misuse at this level]
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:mapping  forKeyPath:@"articles"];


    //serializing post object
    RKObjectMapping* outSerializationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:      [NSMutableDictionary class] ];
    // [If class attributes names are same as JSON's, don't repeat]
    [outSerializationMapping mapAttributes:@"userId", @"mode", nil];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:authSerializationMapping forClass:[BasicUserArgVo class] ]; 


    //setting post object router
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router routeClass:[BasicUserArgVo class] 
            toResourcePath:@"/getMyOffersCount" 
                 forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];


}


- (void)run{

    //init post object
    BasicUserArgVo *bvo = [[BasicUserArgVo alloc]initWithUserId:5 andMode:nil];

    //post object BasicUserArgVo and map to CountResultVO
    RKObjectMapping* myMapping = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[CountResultVO class] ];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:bvo mapResponseWith:myMapping  delegate:self];

}

- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObject:(NSArray*)objects {
NSLog(@"hello");
CountResultVO* countResultVO = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"RESULT : %ld %ld",[countResultVO offercount],[countResultVO insertCount]);

}

- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]]);
}
```

Comment: still no activity in the server, is there some permission i need to add to make network calls ?

Comment: and - (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError *)error; method is called ?

Comment: Nope, 
here's my restKitUtil class
`code`
    @interface RestKitUtil :  NSObject <RKObjectLoaderDelegate,RKRequestDelegate>
    {
      @public NSString *URL;
      @public NSString *METHOD;
    }
    -(void)construct;
    -(void)run;
`code`

Comment: this is my project, restkit is files not included.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19489672/RKitPOC.zip

the backend doesnt get any post.